# implementing interfaces with collections of interfaces

Tags: oop

let's say I have a interface IPerson that expose a collection of another interface ICar. ICar is implemented by the Car class, and the IPerson is implemented by the Person class. I would like that Person could expose a collection of Car, and not of ICar, but this does not seem possible without changing the IPerson interface.

Is there any other solution ? I would like to have the IPerson expose a collection of ICar, but I would also need a class implementing IPerson and exposind a collection of Car.

Thanks

Comment: I think the question is: Why do you want to code to interfaces (IPerson), when you don't want to code to interfaces (Car)? Are you going to have several implementations of IPerson and ICar?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solution will fit your needs, however depending on what language you are using, you could use a generic solution to achieve this kind of behavior.

For example in java

```
interface IPerson<T extends ICar> {

    public T[] getCars();

   // ...
}
```

This will insure that the generic type `T` must implement `ICar`, then in your implementation of `Person` you can have

```
Class Person implements IPerson<Car> {

   Car[] cars;

   public Car[] getCars() {
        return cars;
   }

   // ...
}
```

This will unfortunately not allow you to look at a collection of different `IPersons` together, since this is no longer an `IPerson` but an `IPerson<Car>`.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you can just add a collection of type ICar to your Person class. Because a collection of ICar or Car are (ALMOST) the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion this is not possible.

If IPerson has a collection of ICars, then your Person class also needs to accept any ICar, not just your concrete *Car* class.

This is of course assuming that the user of IPerson is allowed to add ICar instances. If the collection is readonly, then in theory this might be possible but most languages won't allow it (C# for instance will not).